# Determine distance from user to screen with raspberry pi sensors

Tags: opencv, camera, raspberry-pi, distance

I have a Raspberry Pi connected to a monitor and a camera tracking the user. I would like to know the distance of the user to the screen (or to the camera if that is better). Preferably I would like to know the distance from the users face straight to the screen.

Can I do this with just one camera and OpenCV? What about with two cameras?
Otherwise, should I just use a different sensor like the ultrasonic sensor? Is this sensor appropriate if it's below or on the side of the screen? What type of spread/'field of view' does it have?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two cameras, I think, by comparing how far the images are displaced, and using some trigonometry. The math will be non-trivial, however. This sounds like a good application for an ultrasonic sensor. The popular HC-SR04 gives pretty accurate (for my purposes) readings from about 30cm to 2m, provided the object is on-axis. I get *some* useful measurements for objects up to about 20 degrees off axis, but it's considerably less accurate. You can connect a HC-SR04 to the GPIO pins, but I prefer to use commercial i2c interfaces, because doing the timing in the Pi CPU is a pain. In any event, the HC-SR04 is so cheap that you haven't lost a great deal if you buy one just to experiment with.

Comment: Should the sensor be accurate enough for detecting the distance of a person? I read that it doesn't work so well for softer items i.e. a jumper

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't carried out exhaustive tests on fabrics :) I can confirm that the HC-SR04 will detect the presence of legs wearing clothing, because I've used them at ground level. But how accurate they are, I really couldn't say. My guess would be that whilst clothing might disperse the sound wave, I don't think it would slow it down. You're still measuring the time taken for the sound wave to reflect from the object and, I think, if it reflects at all, that time would be roughly the same. But I have no evidence to back this up.